# Exclude field from mongoose schema when created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got this schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: value => {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error({error: 'Invalid Email address'});
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 7,
        select: false
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
    }]
});

and controller for creating the user:

const register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        await user.save();
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        res.status(201).send({user, token});
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).send({error});
    }
}
```

in response there is all information including password, which is dangerous for me. What is the preferred way for doing it. I know about dto, but don't want to have it on project. I'm not querying the database so I can't use exclude, select or other methods which can get rid of password.

Answer (score 2):

You have already `select: false` option for the password field, so it will not retrieved in find methods.

For the issue in register, you can delete the password from the user like this:

```
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        await user.save();
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        delete user.password;
        res.status(201).send({user, token});
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).send({error});
    }
```